# DataTables not working - Ignited Datatable Library

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

I have used ignited datable to integrate it in codeigniter but getting following error : DataTables warning: table id=example2 - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example2').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sServerMethod": "POST",
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url()?>auth/datatable"
    } );            
} );
```

Here is my html

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

here is the json generated

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":2,"data":[{"email":"admin@admin.com","first_name":"Admin","last_name":"istrator"},{"email":"subhadeepgayen@gmail.com","first_name":"Subhadeep","last_name":"Gayen"}]}
```

can seem to find any solution :(

Answer (score 4):

Hello you need only specify the columns

```
"columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "name" }
              ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this - http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/160896/

And also this - http://www.ahmed-samy.com/php-codeigniter-full-featrued-jquery-datatables-part-1/

Do let me know if you succeed.

Best